# What would be the most efficient approach to to determine if there exist two integers X and Y in a sorted sequence such that X XNOR Y = -1?

Tags: python-3.x

The problem is as below:

```
Given a sequence of positive integers, SEQ, sorted in ascending order, design and
implement an algorithm with Python to determine if there exist two integers X and Y in
the sorted sequence such that X XNOR Y = -1.

For example, if SEQ is provided to your program as follows:
SEQ:
1 2 3 3 4 4 4 10 10 10

The sample output is given below:
X=3, Y=3
X=4, Y=4
X=4, Y=4
X=4, Y=4
X=10, Y=10
X=10, Y=10
X=10, Y=10
Total match is 7.
```

I had tried 2 for loops but I would like to find more efficient methods. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why is `X=3;Y=3` exists only once and the `X=4;Y=4` exists 3 times?

Comment: X=4;Y=4 exists 3 times, as there is 3 instances of 4; 4(1), 4(2), 4(3), such that 4(1) = 4(2), 4(1) = 4(3), and 4(2) = 4(3).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using itertools and a bit of combinatorics, you can easily do it in `O(n)`:

```
import math, itertools
data = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10]
total = 0
for k, g in itertools.groupby(data):
    combinations = math.comb(len(list(g)), 2)
    total += combinations
    print(f"X={k}, Y={k}\n"*combinations, end="")

print("Total =", total)
```

For `int XNOR int = -1`, the integers have to be the same (`int^int=0` only when both integers are the same, and `~0 ==  -1`).

I therefore group all of the same integers in one pass, and for each group calculate nCr using "`(group_length)C2`".

Output:

```
X=3, Y=3
X=4, Y=4
X=4, Y=4
X=4, Y=4
X=10, Y=10
X=10, Y=10
X=10, Y=10
Total = 7
```

Comment: Why the -1? Correct output and fast.